# Get only N months data indexed in a Collection. It should be on rolling based

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing, nosql

Currently I am facing an issue that a MongoDB collection might have billion records which contains document based on some rapid event happening in the system. These events get logged in the DB collection.

Since we have some 2-3 composite indexing on the same collection, the search definitely becomes slow.

The escape point to this is our customer has agreed if we can index only N months data in the MongoDB, then the efficiency for read can increase instead of having 2-3 years data indexed and we perform read operation.

**My thoughts on solution 1:** we can do TTL indexes and set expiry. After this expiry the data gets deleted from main collection. we can some how do backup for that expired records. This way we can only have specific data required in main collection.

**My thoughts on solution 2:** I can remove all the indexes, create the indexes again based on time frame, for example, Drop current indexes and again create indexes based on condition that indexes must be created only till past N months data only. This way I can maintain limited index. But I am not sure how much is it possible.

> **Question**: I need more help on this on how can I achieve selective indexing. Also it must be rolling as everyday records gets added so does indexing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Mongo 3.2 or above, you should be able to use a partial index to create the "selective index" that you want -- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#index-type-partial You'll just need to be sure that your queries share the same partial filter expression that the index has.

(I suspect that there might also be issues with the indexes you currently have, and that reducing index size won't necessarily have a huge impact on search duration. Mongo indexes are stored in a B-tree, so the time to navigate the tree to find a single item is going to scale relative to the log of the number of items. It might be worth examining the explain output for the queries that you have to see what mongo is actually doing.)

Comment: I looked into this a bit further -- I'm wrong about partial indexes being able to be selective in a rolling fashion. Instead, you'll need to manually mark the documents that you want to be indexed & use that mark in the partial index filter expression

Comment: thanks for your time but I guess, this will not work.

Comment: Yeah, what I wrote here won't work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57835524/how-to-create-a-partial-index-with-variable-date/57844112 is a similiar question about partial indexes that might be useful

Comment: Yes! It is useful. Well though