# How to create a partial index with variable date?

Tags: mongodb

I want to create a partial index in MongoDB which excludes documents that are older than 30 days in the past from the current date.

Something like this (pseudo code):

```
partialFilterExpression: { date: { $gte: { $currentDate - 30 days }} }
```

The `$currentDate` should be the actual current date, in other words the date is a dynamic value, not a static value.

It this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, dynamic values in the filter expression are not currently supported with partial indexes & the filter expression only supports a subset of regular mongo query operators (and that subset does not include the `$date` operator).

One way to approximate your desired behavior is by creating a `shouldIndex` boolean field on your documents, have `{shouldIndex: true}` be your filter expression, and have a script update that field once a day for documents that are older than `current_date - 30`.

Comment: I am tempted to mark this as correct, but I'll wait a bit maybe there are other ideas.

Answer (score -2):

Yes that's possible,

you can use normal **createIndex** operation with **partialFilterExpression** which contains you condition.

I think code in you quenstion will only work

You can use

```
let today = new Date();    //your date condition

db.collection_name.createIndex({ field1 : type1, field2: type2},
            partialFilterExpression: { date: { $gte: { today }} })
```

Read more about parital indexes [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/),

however it comes with some restrictions too.

Comment: Looks like `today` will be the static value of the time of index creation.

Comment: No, today will be the date when you will be running your script.

Comment: The script will only run once to create the index. `Today` will have the value of the time when the script ran. That value will not change anymore.

Comment: Okay, you want that, if new Documents are getting inserted then this filter should also be applied on them too!